# Determining the maximum RAM I can upgrade my PC to and what type

Tags: upgrade, memory

Im having a little trouble determining what memory to buy and what the maximum I can upgrade to. I currently have 2GB and wish to upgrade to 3 or 4GB. I know with 32bit Vista I will only achieve max 3.5GB - if that.

I have a Medion PC which is model number PC MT 7. I have tried looking for the model at crucial.com (the closest they have is PC MT 5 which clearly isn't it with maximum RAM of 1GB). Also their scanning tool didn't come up with a result.

I have found out that my motherboard is Micro Star MS-7538. However looking for its specification has yielded no results.

Is there any other routes I could go to find out what I need? I bought the PC brand new in about 2007. Is it safe to assume that such recent models would be DDR2 and can hande 4GB or is there other factors I need to consider?

Thanks!

Comment: have you opened the case? how many RAM slots does the motherboard have?  how many are currently in use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may find that the free [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php) utility offers some useful information.  Certainly some of the information is overkill, but I have used this before to find my exact motherboard model number and the specs of my current RAM, which helped me answer your exact question (by enabling me to Google the motherboard model as retrieved from the motherboard itself.)

EDIT: Per ~quack's comment above, CPU-Z will tell you how many RAM slots you have empty or filled, without needing to get under your desk to open the case itself.  :)

> CPU-Z is a freeware that gathers
>   information on some of the main
>   devices of your system.
>
> CPU
>
> - Name and number.
> - Core stepping and process.
> - Package.
> - Core voltage.
> - Internal and external clocks, clock multiplier.
> - Supported instructions sets.
> - Cache information.
>
> Mainboard
>
> - Vendor, model and revision.
> - BIOS model and date.
> - Chipset (northbridge and southbridge) and sensor.
> - Graphic interface.
>
> Memory
>
> - Frequency and timings.
> - Module(s) specification using SPD (Serial Presence Detect) : vendor,
>     serial number, timings table.
>
> System
>
> - Windows and DirectX version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CPU-Z (http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php), SIW (http://www.gtopala.com/) or Speccy (http://www.piriform.com/speccy) to examine available memory slots in your computer as well as the type and speed of memory currently installed.

I'd guess that if you have available slots it may be safe to double the RAM you have in there. Easiest option is to take the computer to your local computer dealer (I prefer small shops) and they can quickly experiment with what your computer will take.

4GB is a sort of usable limit for 32-bit operating systems, your motherboard may or may not support more (or less).

Comment: +1 for CPUZ and the 32bit comment, -1 for "Easiest option is to take the computer to your local computer dealer". Since when is transporting a PC easy, and local computer dealers cheap :P

Comment: Thanks, I was using Speccy to get the motherboard model. I took a closer look at the Memory info provided and currently there are 2 x 1GB DDR2 with max badwidth PC2-5300. So I know I possibly need http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/partspecs.aspx?IMODULE=CT2KIT12864AC667 (I have 2 free slots). However how do I know if 200-pin SODIMM is correct? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm spoiled, been dealing with an awesome small shop less than 5 minutes drive. At minimum they price match any price I throw at them, quite often beating it. http://kingswaycomputer.com highly recommended for people in Vancouver area.

Comment: @chamoon: not many desktop computers use the SODIMM, if none of the programs mention it you can do a visual inspection of your currently installed ram

Comment: Upon visual inspection your are right, its not SODIMM. http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/partspecs.aspx?IMODULE=CT2KIT12864AA667 seems to be correct!

Answer (score 1):

there are about **[30 different Medion MT7 models](http://www.memory4more.com/show.cgi?ID=medion.htm)**, take your pick.

Examples:

PC MT7 MED MT272

512MB (removable), 4GB max, 4 ports.

PC MT7 MET MT515

1GB (removable), 2GB max, 2 ports.

Comment: As with all OEM system builders, you have to go back to them for specifications. While the board is an MSI made, I can't find any info on their website. This is common because these devices sometimes get re-branded by the OEM. I would match new memory to whatever you currently have installed. If you have 2 ports, you may be maxed out, if you have 4, then you can probably expand. In most cases, if you have too big of memory sticks, your motherboard will just not see the extra space. It simply can't address the additional locations.

Comment: @Doltknuckle - well, as i said, there are at least 30 different MT7 models, the exact model should be found either on a sticker or in the documentation, and then take it from there. but yes, if there are 4 slots, then 4GB is a safe bet :)