# Can I find the exact type of RAM without looking inside?

Tags: memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determining the maximum RAM I can upgrade my PC to and what type](https://superuser.com/questions/101362/determining-the-maximum-ram-i-can-upgrade-my-pc-to-and-what-type)

There are [similar](https://superuser.com/questions/27006/how-to-check-ram-size-without-looking-at-motherboard) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/214466/how-to-identify-different-types-of-ram) but nothing exactly about this:

**Without opening the computer, how can I determine what kind of RAM to buy?**

I want to max out my RAM to get a cheap and simple performance improvement. I know I'm running a 32-bit OS and upgrading to 4GB will only give me 3GB, but I could consider going 64-bit later on so I really do want 4GB.

I've got the machine specs *sort-of* but not so precise that I can deduce the exact RAM format. I know I've got 4 slots, 2 of which are in use with 1GB in each.

I could open the machines (there are two different machines), count the pins, photograph the RAM sticks, and post everything here -- but I'd rather not unplug and open the machines because they're tucked a bit out of the way. I know I need to open the machines to install the RAM anyway, but I'd prefer to open them only once.

Is there another way to identify the RAM precisely enough to be able to order more RAM based on that information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to [Cruical.com](http://www.crucial.com/index.aspx) and run their test. It will tell you.

You could alternatively use [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) or some other alternative, there are plenty out there.

Comment: All the suggested tools gave me the same answer, so I feel I can trust the results. Crucial's tool is the only one that told me that the "maximum memory capacity" is 2GB --> can I trust that?! It sounds to me like if I replace the 2 x 1GB sticks with 2 x 2GB then either my computer won't run or it will run with only 2GB - can that be the case!?

Answer (score 6):

[CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) should display the RAM info for you. Have a look on the memory tab, there should be a drop down list containing entries for each slot you have.

Edit: Sorry, the drop down list is on the SPD tab.

Answer (score 0):

A program like [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) will tell you exactly what model of RAM you have, and plenty more about it.