# Does my motherboard really only support 2GB of RAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I want to max out the RAM in my computers, but [tools like Crucial and Speccy](https://superuser.com/questions/214784/can-i-find-the-exact-type-of-ram-without-looking-inside-closed) tell me that the "maximum memory capacity" is only 2GB! The RAM type is DDR2 PC2-5300.

This surprises me because the machines are fairly new, and I'd expect the motherboards to support 4GB. I'm not at home right now so I can't tell you specifics about the motherboard.

**Is it likely that my motherboards really only support 2GB?**
(That would suck because an upgrade would require replacing more hardware than I expected.)

Comment: ... Which motherboards?

Comment: Does Speccy tell "just" the number of free memory slots available and the technical info of RAM inserted into slots?

Comment: @Ignacio, I did mention that I'm not at home right now so I can't tell you specifics about the motherboard.

Comment: @Aki: Speccy tells the exact RAM units as well as used and total numbr of RAM slots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If two sources are confirm the same thing then I would have to say yes the test are correct. The only real way of being for sure is checking with manufacturer's website or documentation of the motherboard, if custom built, or the computer, if bought pre-built with a proprietary motherboard such as a Dell.

I didn't find anything about Crucial's scan being inaccarate...
[How accurate is crucial memory system scan? -- Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how+accarate+is+crucial+memory+upgrade+test%3F#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=how+accurate+is+crucial+memory+system+scan%3F&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=how+accurate+is+crucial+memory+system+scan%3F&gs_rfai=&fp=94fb864a6b447b62)